# Ignore table column value in select with joins

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables

table1 fields - id, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
table2 fields - id, field3

What i need is result of this query

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.field1,
    t1.field2,
    t2.field3,
    t1.field4,
    t1.field5
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE 1
```

The problem I'm having is that I have more similar tables and in some cases table1 fields may not be 6 fields, but 50 fields.

That is why I need to make query look like

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.field3 as field3
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE 1
```

but in this query t1.field3 is selecting and showing in query result.

Can someone give an idea how to make my first query look like second query and return the result of the first query.

Comment: `t1.*` will retrieve all the fields of the table, you cannot then exclude one of these columns. Rename field3 from the other table to something distinctive, so that you can then ignore t1.field3 in any further processing.

Comment: Write a quick program to generate the text of the queries.

Comment: (Why do similar tables vary between 6 and 50 fields? That seems a red flag in terms of database structure.)

Comment: #Andy G - for your first comment, that can be done, but then I have in php do additional processing, which I want to avoid. for your second comment I mean I have other similar cases with more fields in the first table and basicly I want to avoid writing all those fields in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with plain SQL, you can achieve with some programming using stored procedures, generating dynamic queries by first reading the column names from the table and then generating the query